# Two operations on an array of bits in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

```
// b: uint32_t array of size n    => 32*n bits
// The bit index, i, is in the range 0 <= i < 32 * n
// The bit in b at bit index 0 is always 0!

unsigned idx_of_first_zero_bit_before_or_at (uint32_t *b, unsigned n, unsigned i) {
    // Returns a bit index, k, such that k <= i and k is the largest bit index
    // for which bit k in b is 0.
}

// As above, value == 0 or 1
void set_bit (uint32_t *b, unsigned n, unsigned i, unsigned value) {
    // Sets bit at bit index i to value.
    // It could be something like (untested):
    if (value)
        b[i >> 5] |=   (1 << (i&31));
    else
        b[i >> 5] &= (~(1 << (i&31)));
}
```

I'm looking for the most efficient, but still portable (across different targets, but only g++ compiler is used) way to implement these functions (especially the first one). Storage order of the bits (big, little endian or anything else) doesn't matter.

Naive implementation (untested):

```
uint32_t get_bit (uint32_t *b, unsigned n, unsigned i) {
    return b[i >> 5] & (1 << (i&31));
}

unsigned idx_of_first_zero_bit_before_or_at (uint32_t *b, unsigned n, unsigned i) {
    while (get_bit (b, n, i)) 
        i--;
    return i;
}
```

Skipping all-1-elements:

```
unsigned idx_of_first_zero_bit_before_or_at (uint32_t *b, unsigned n, unsigned i) {
    for (unsigned k = i >> 5; ~(b[k]) == 0; i = (--k << 5) + 31);
    while (get_bit (b, n, i)) 
        i--;
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Your untested `get_bit` seems to check everything (in the relevant 32-bit value) except the bit in question. Just leave out the inversion. :-) For optimization, think about skipping 32-bit values that are all 1's, easily checked by inverting and checking for 0. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @Alf: Thanks, tried to add your solution - maybe not as good as possible...

Comment: GCC has some extensions, __builtin_clz for example, so you can use those if you only need to use GCC. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html

Comment: @mu: I had looked at them, but I couldn't think of a reasonable way to use them for this algorithm (still, that might be possible).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how much storage you have available, you can take a lookup-table approach.  For instance, if you can spend 256 bytes, then the following function does it for a single `uint32_t`:

```
static const int table[256] = { 
    7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
    7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
    7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
    7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
    7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
    7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
    7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
    7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0,
};


int func(uint32_t b, int i)
{
    b = (b << (31-i));

    if ((b & 0xFFFF0000) != 0xFFFF0000)
    {
        return ((b & 0xFF000000) != 0xFF000000)
             ? table[(b >> 24) & 0xFF] + 24 - (31-i)
             : table[(b >> 16) & 0xFF] + 16 - (31-i);
    }
    else
    {
        return ((b & 0xFF00) != 0xFF00)
             ? table[(b >> 8) & 0xFF] + 8 - (31-i)
             : table[(b >> 0) & 0xFF] + 0 - (31-i);
    }
}
```

I'm sure this can be optimised further.  For instance, there are certainly ways to eliminate the expensive conditional branches; you can use the fact that boolean conditions evaluate to either `1` or `0`, and use them as multiplicands.

If you have 64kB available, then you do this on 16-bit chunks at a time, and so on.  Of course, doing random access on a large table might bring caching effects into play, so you'll need to experiment, and profile.

Comment: Nice idea! I'll optimize it for my platform and compare.

Comment: @Thomas: Now that you're using the "skip all `0xFFFFFFFF`s approach", I suspect that for long enough arrays, your runtime will be dominated by the skipping loop.  So it may not be worth the hassle of optimising the above routine...

Answer (score 0):

Usually I try avoiding "random" branches. For example, we can take the solution proposed by Oli Charlesworth, and get rid of the `if`s.

It solves most of the calculations with a [LUT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table), but the last part still requires branches. Introduce an additional LUT to deal with it:

```
unsigned index2 = table[ b        & 0xFF]        |  // Values 0..7, so we use 3 bits
                 (table[(b >>  8) & 0xFF] << 3 ) |  // Next 3 bits..
                 (table[(b >> 16) & 0xFF] << 6 ) |
                 (table[(b >> 24) & 0xFF] << 9 );
```

Now we have a 12-bit value in `index2` that we can transform to a meaningful value with a single table lookup:

```
return table2[index2]; // char[4096] array with precomputed values.
```

Also, by using a 16-bit LUT in the first place, we'll end up with two 16-bit lookups and an 8-bit one.

Comment: This should yield a good improvement. Unfortunately, my platform has only 256kB of memory - 4096+256 bytes would already be a lot for this algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use binary search to find a zero bit within one uint32.  You can also replace the last few steps with a lookup table to balance the LUT's memory footprint against instructions.  First, a solution with control flow:

```
unsigned idx_of_first_zero_bit(uint32_t n) {
  int idx = 0;
  if (n == 0xffffffff) return 32;  // Not found; presumably the common case

  // Binary search
  if (n & 0xffff == 0xffff) {
    n >>= 16;
    idx += 16;
  }
  if (n & 0xff == 0xff) {
    n >>= 8;
    idx += 8;
  }
  if (n & 0xf == 0xf) {
    n >>= 4;
    idx += 4;
  }
  if (n & 0x3 == 0x3) {
    n >>= 2;
    idx += 2;
  }
  if (n & 0x1 == 0x1) {
    n >>= 1;
    idx += 1;
  }
  return idx;
}
```

To avoid branch mispredictions, you can effect conditional update with bitwise operations.

```
int shift;

// First step
shift = ((n & 0xffff == 0xffff) << 4); // shift = (n & 0xffff == 0xffff) ? 16 : 0
n >>= shift;
idx += shift;

// Next step
shift = ((n & 0xff == 0xff) << 3); // shift = (n & 0xff == 0xff) ? 8 : 0
n >>= shift;
idx += shift;
```